# Jquery dialog - How apply buttons color?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dialog

I would like to apply the color to jquery dialog buttons.I'm trying to set the color in CSS , but not relecting.I have three buttons Search,edit,close. ow to set the some colors ?

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset button:first-child {
  right: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -385px;
  background-color : red;

}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NrYVM/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default { background:red;}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NrYVM/5/)

you just have to be more specific with your selectors than the UI stylesheet to overwrite the styles.